# How can I add a caption to the images in this existing Jquery image gallery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to add a list of image titles (text) that would appear and disapear depending on the image in front of the gallery.
the is from this code pen [code pen](https://codepen.io/atomikdesign/pen/KpoJGw?page=1&)

I've tried to create a list of strings containing the titles , but the result was that titles are displayed all at once.

this is the part of code I've tried to add the list in .. please check the wholle code at code pen

```
    card.addClass("photo").css({
            "top": i * -6 + "px",
            "left": (i * 4.5) + "px",
            "width": 100-i*5 + "%",
            "background": bgColor
        }).appendTo(gallery);

        var imgContainer = $("<div>").addClass("imgContainer").appendTo(card);
        var img = $("<img>").attr("src", photos[i]).appendTo(imgContainer);
        var membre = $("<div>").addClass("membre").appendTo(card);
        var nom = $("<div>").addClass("nom").appendTo(membre);
        var statut = $("<div>").addClass("statut").appendTo(membre);
    }

    $(".photo").on("click", function() {
        var i=0;
        if ($(this).index() == $(".photo").length - 1 && animation == false)
            $(".nom").text(names[i]);
            i++;
            swipePhoto(this);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `photos array` to keep both `image url` and the `caption text`. Then create another `div` to hold the `caption` and append it to the card same as `image`.

See the below working example.

```js
// Images from http://megatruh.deviantart.com/

$(document).ready(function() {
  var photos = [{
      image: "http://pre04.deviantart.net/ef3d/th/pre/f/2014/046/3/e/quiet_calamity_by_megatruh-d76k76f.jpg",
      caption: "Image one caption"
    },
    {
      image: "http://pre07.deviantart.net/6c73/th/pre/f/2014/119/7/7/island___by_megatruh-d7ginlh.jpg",
      caption: "Image two caption"
    },
    {
      image: "http://pre05.deviantart.net/dce1/th/pre/f/2013/361/7/d/somnium_by_megatruh-d6zloar.jpg",
      caption: "Image three caption"
    },
    {
      image: "http://pre03.deviantart.net/7139/th/pre/f/2013/067/d/8/the_world_is_ahead___by_megatruh-d5xchxw.jpg",
      caption: "Image four caption"
    },
    {
      image: "http://pre02.deviantart.net/265c/th/pre/f/2012/326/4/0/a_worthy_brother___by_megatruh-d5luhah.jpg",
      caption: "Image five caption"
    },
    {
      image: "http://pre12.deviantart.net/d18b/th/pre/f/2012/272/d/e/in_asgard___by_megatruh-d5g8nah.jpg",
      caption: "Image six caption"
    }
  ];

  var direction = 1,
    animation = false,
    nbPhotos = photos.length,
    gallery = $("#gallery");

  function init() {
    for (var i = nbPhotos - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var color = 255 - i * 10,
        bgColor = "rgba(" + color + ", " + color + ", " + color + ", 1)",
        card = $("<div>");

      card
        .addClass("photo")
        .css({
          top: i * -6 + "px",
          left: i * 4.5 + "px",
          width: 100 - i * 5 + "%",
          background: bgColor
        })
        .appendTo(gallery);

      //Append caption container to the card
      ///////////////////////////////////////

      var captionContainer = $("<div>")
        .addClass("captionContainer")
        .html(photos[i].caption)
        .appendTo(card);

      //////////////////////////////////////

      var imgContainer = $("<div>")
        .addClass("imgContainer")
        .appendTo(card);
      var img = $("<img>")
        .attr("src", photos[i].image)
        .appendTo(imgContainer);
    }

    $(".photo").on("click", function() {
      if ($(this).index() == $(".photo").length - 1 && animation == false)
        swipePhoto(this);
    });
  }

  function swipePhoto(elem) {
    animation = true;
    var photo = $(elem);

    var animationsDone = 0;

    function animationDone() {
      animationsDone++;
      if (animationsDone >= nbPhotos) {
        $(".photo").attr("animating", false);
        animation = false;
      }
    }

    // Animation: photo swipe
    photo.attr("animating", true);
    photo.animate({
        top: "+=" + 30,
        left: direction + "=" + 250
      },
      500,
      "easeInQuart",
      function() {
        // Photo goes behind all photos (DOM)
        photo.detach();
        photo.prependTo(gallery);

        var color = 255 - 4 * 10;
        var bgColor = "rgba(" + color + "," + color + "," + color + ", 1)";

        // Animation of the photo going behind
        photo
          .animate({
              top: (nbPhotos - 1) * -6 + "px",
              left: (nbPhotos - 1) * 4.5 + "px",
              width: 100 - (nbPhotos - 1) * 5 + "%"
            },
            900,
            "easeOutQuart",
            animationDone
          )
          .css("background", bgColor);
      }
    );

    // Update animation direction
    if (direction == "+") direction = "-";
    else direction = "+";

    // Animation : each photo move to his correct position
    var j = 0;
    for (var i = nbPhotos - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var color = 225 + i * 12;
      var bgColor = "rgba(" + color + "," + color + "," + color + ", 1)";
      if ($(".photo:eq(" + i + ")").attr("animating") !== "true") {
        $(".photo:eq(" + i + ")")
          .delay((nbPhotos - i + 1) * 150)
          .animate({
              top: j * -6 + "px",
              left: j * 4.5 + "px",
              width: 100 - j * 5 + "%"
            },
            500,
            "easeOutBack",
            animationDone
          )
          .css("background", bgColor);
        j++;
      }
    }
  }

  init();
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla");
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #F0E5ED;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 3px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
  background: #9cafbc;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.heading,
#gallery {
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 200px;
}

.heading {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.heading h1 {
  margin: 0 auto 5px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.heading span {
  font-size: .65em;
  font-weight: 900;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#gallery {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 20px 0 0;
  height: 200px;
}

#gallery .photo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF, #CFCFCF, #FFFFFF);
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

#gallery .photo:last-child {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#gallery .photo .captionContainer {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 4px;
  bottom: 9px;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: block;
}

#gallery .photo .imgContainer {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#gallery .photo .imgContainer img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Handlee' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="container">
  <div class="heading">
    <h1>Gallery concept</h1>
    <span>Click on the first image</span>
  </div>
  <div id="gallery"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help you. You can mark it as the correct answer if it helped you to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks it worked ..
Actually I wanted the titles (caption) to be independente .. 
to be in an independente div out of the images tag.. (below them)